# Riemann Liouville fractional integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators, fractional-calculus

I am preparing an article about the Riemann-Liouville fractional integral. Im stuck in the following (some explanation will be thankful):

The left sided Riemann-Liouville fractional integral of order $0<\alpha<1$ is defined by:

$$J_{0+}^\alpha f(t):=\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^t\frac{f(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha}}\mathrm d\tau,\quad t>0$$

Where $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is the Euler Gamma function. The integral above can be written as the convolution:

$$J_{0+}^\alpha f(t):=(\psi_\alpha\circ f)(t)$$

where

$$\phi_\alpha:=\begin{cases}0,&t\ge 0\\\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},&t<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: İf there any explanation

Comment: Explanation of what?  You seem to be stating things as though this is a blog and not a question.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence containing "stuck on the idea..." (I think this is the case for @Simply Beautiful Art). What do you refer as "the idea" ?  The last formulas that you aren't able to prove ?

Comment: Yes sorry for my english

Comment: you need to say what is, exactly, what you dont understand.

Comment: @user435757 :  I don't perceive what is actually the problem precisely. Is it the motivation to introduce the fractional differ-integration theory ? Or the mathematical background and developments? Or how to prepare such an article? You may find some elementary ideas and material in the general-public essay (pages 7-12 in English) : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire